# How to implement socket.io connection in RoboSpice Android

Tags: android, socket.io, robospice

I'm using RoboSpice + Spring Android for developing a chat application in Android.
How to integrate socket.io connection in RoboSpice? so that i can maintain socket connections between activities.

Socket io code

```
              try {
        socket = new SocketIO("http://server.com");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
         }
            socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("an Error occured");
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            }

            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
                System.out.println("Message : '" + args[0] + "'");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RoboSpice, networking is managed at the Request level. Hence, your request should use the socket io lib.

Socket IO is not provided as a module of RoboSpice. I didn't even know it before seeing your question. What exactly would you expect from RoboSpice when using Socket IO ?

Comment: I want to leverage RoboSpice for socket.io connection. Instead of creating a service for socket.io i want RoboSpice to handle it and add a listener for listening to events. I don't know whether this is possible or not, may be like an always open connection runs as a service created by RoboSpice.

Comment: Hi @sooraj.e,  it is currently not possible to use RoboSpice with Socket.io API. RoboSpice's architecture more or less fits with websockets. It would be possible to create a new module for it, but a lot of questions would need to be answered. I created issue #71 in RS for that : https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/issues/71. Feel free to participate to it.